# Why am I getting this error when trying to unzip a file?

Tags: tar, unzip

```
tar -xjf employees_db-full-1.0.6.tar.bz2
employees_db/load_salaries.dump: (Empty error message)
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

I'm trying to unzip a SQL database so I can play around with it with select statements but I don't know why I can't even do Step 1 (set up).

Comment: are you using OSX or Linux? what is the version of tar, run tar --version .

Comment: try gnutar instead of tar , if gnutar is not found, try to install it : brew install gnu-tar then: cd /usr/bin then: sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin/tar gnutar

Answer (score 0):

Couple of reasons that could lead to above error:

- Either you don't have much space left
- tar file is not valid or complete
- You don't have adequate permission to untar the file.